# Python Django App Moving Through Pagination In Api Response

Tags: python, django, pagination

I made an API call to a restful service that by default comes with 100 paginated pages.

I have been working with my response and even built search functions into the app but I cannot figure out how to use the pagination.

Would someone please explain how I should move through the pagination of the response?

From the api

> The pagination info is included in the Link header. It is important
>   to follow these Link header values instead of constructing your own
>   URLs.

[image]

And this is the current view I am working with. I have a plus and minus button in my search controls. I was hoping to allow people to move forward or backwards through the pagination with these controls. Is this not just a url I need to hit to move forward?

When I add `rel="next"` to the end of the url it just reloads the same results.

here is my view for reference.

```
def graphs(request):
    mtg_url = 'https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards'
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = []
            mtg_colors = request.POST.get('colors')
            mtg_type = request.POST.get('type')
            mtg_supertypes = request.POST.get('supertypes')
            mtg_subtypes = request.POST.get('subtypes')
            mtg_name = request.POST.get('mtgName')
            type_search = '?color='+mtg_colors+'&type='+mtg_type+'&supertypes='+mtg_supertypes+'&subtypes='+mtg_subtypes
            nameSearch = '/typeahead?q='+mtg_name
            if mtg_name == "":
                r = requests.get(mtg_url+type_search)
                print(r)
            else:
                r = requests.get(mtg_url+nameSearch)
            jsonList = r.json()
            for cards in jsonList:
                data.append(cards)
                print(data)
            return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'data': data})
        else:
            data = []
            r = requests.get(mtg_url)
            jsonList = r.json()
            for cards in jsonList:
                data.append(cards)
            return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'data': data})
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Response in JSON

```
[
  {
    "name": "_____",
    "id": "_____",
    "url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards/_____",
    "store_url": "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/unhinged/_____?partner=DECKBREW",
    "types": [
      "creature"
    ],
    "subtypes": [
      "shapeshifter"
    ],
    "colors": [
      "blue"
    ],
    "cmc": 2,
    "cost": "{1}{U}",
    "text": "{1}: This card's name becomes the name of your choice. Play this ability anywhere, anytime.",
    "power": "1",
    "toughness": "1",
    "formats": {},
    "editions": [
      {
        "set": "Unhinged",
        "set_id": "UNH",
        "rarity": "uncommon",
        "artist": "Ron Spears",
        "multiverse_id": 74252,
        "flavor": "{1}: This card's flavor text becomes the flavor text of your choice. (This ability doesn't work because it's flavor text, not rules text (but neither does this reminder text, so you figure it out).)",
        "number": "23",
        "layout": "normal",
        "price": {
          "low": 0,
          "median": 0,
          "high": 0
        },
        "url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?multiverseid=74252",
        "image_url": "https://image.deckbrew.com/mtg/multiverseid/74252.jpg",
        "set_url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets/UNH",
        "store_url": "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/unhinged/_____?partner=DECKBREW"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: can you post a dummy response?

Comment: I edited my question and added the first element of the json response at the end.